# Variational formulation, weak formulation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'd like to find the weak formulation of the problem

$-u''+au=f$ on $(0,1)$ 
$u(0)=0$ 
$u'(1)=b$ 
$a>0$ 
and show that there exists a unique solution using Lax-Milgram.

What I did:
By multiplying the first term with a test function $v$ and doing partial integration I get that
\begin{align}
-\int_{0}^{1}u''(t)v(t)dt=-u'(1)v(1)+u'(0)v(0)+\int_{0}^{1}u'(t)v'(t)dt.
\end{align}
Since I want the first part of the equation to be zero, I set $v \in H_{0}^{1}$.
So the formulation of the problem is

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}u'(t)v'(t)dt+a\int_{0}^{1}u(t)v(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)v(t)dt
\end{align}
for all $v \in H^{1}_{0}$

Is that part correct? I'm confused where the boundary condition $u'(1)=b$ is taken into account. Is $u$ in $H^{1}_{0}$ as well or do I need to define a new space

$ V=\{v \in L^2(0,1), v' \in L^2(0,1), v'(1)=b, v(0)=0\}$?

For the second part of the question (uniqueness + existence of solution):
Using Cauchy Schwarz I get for the bilinear form $a(u,v)$
\begin{align}
|a(u,v)|=\int_{0}^{1}u'(t)v'(t)+au(t)v(t)dt \leq ||u'||_{L^2}||v'||_{L^2}+a||u||_{L^2}||v||_{L^2}\leq||u'||_{H^{1}_{0}}||v||_{H^{1}_{0}}+a||u||_{H^{1}_{0}}||v||_{H^{1}_{0}}
\end{align}
So this shows continuity of $a$.
I'm not sure though which norm to use for $u$ since I'm not sure which space to choose.
Using Poincare I get
\begin{align}
|a(u,u)|=||u'||_{L^2}^2+a||u||_{L^2}^2 \geq ||u'||_{L^2}^2 \geq C ||u||_{L^2}^2
\end{align}
showing that the bilinear form is coercive.
The last thing I need to show is that $F$, my linear functional, is continuous (bounded). This follows from
\begin{align}
|F(v)| \leq ||f||_{L^2}||v||_{L^2} \leq ||f||_{L^2}||v||_{H^1_0}
\end{align}
Hence, using Lax Milgram I've shown existence and uniqueness of a solution.

Is it correct what I am doing? I am very new to this topic so I am not so sure about some steps, expecially how to choose the space for my $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it!

An essential thing to remember when attempting to use Lax-Milgram is that the solution space and the test function space have to be the same! Which seems you did not achieve here. Here is a better approach.

You use $v \in V$ so you end up with a weak form: find $u \in V$ such that
$$B(u,v) = L(v),  \ \ \ \ \forall v \in V.$$
Such that
\begin{align*}
&B(u,v) = \int u' v' + a \int u v,\\
&L(v) = \int fv + bv(1) \\
&V=\{v \in H^1, \ \ v(0)=0\}.
\end{align*}
You have already proved that $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is bounded and in this case you use $H^1$ norm. So you get
$$|B(u,v)| \leq (1+a)||u||_{H^1} ||v||_{H^1}.$$
For the coercivity, you do not need Poincare here. You can use
$$|B(u,u)| = \int (u')^2 + a \int (u)^2 \geq \min(1,a) ||u||^2_{H^1}.$$
For the boundedness of $L(\cdot)$
$$|L(v)| \leq  \int |fv| + |bv(1)| \leq ||f||_{L^2} ||v||_{L^2} + |b| \||v||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{L^2} ||v||_{L^2} + |b| \ ||v'||_{L^2} \leq  M ||v||_{H^1}$$
Where M = 2 $ \max(||f||_{L^2}, |b|)$. From here, Lax-Milgram can be used.